# Use Android sources plugin with Eclipse ADT bundle

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, adt

I followed [android.com's](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html) instructions for installing eclipse with android developer tools (ADT) bundle.  I then in eclipse do Help > Install New Software... to attempt to install [Android Source Plugin](http://adt-addons.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/source/com.android.ide.eclipse.source.update/) which I have happily used for at least a year on my old eclipse installation.

Attempting to install it using Java Rel7, I get an error which I found some bug reporting was due to running eclipse on Java Rel7.  So I tried to run Java Rel5 but this version of eclipse needs Java Rel6.  So I installed Java Rel6 and tried running eclipse on that and installing the Android Source Plugin, but that failed too.

Anybody else run in to anything like this?  Know any workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try installing eclipse and the SDK seperately. I've had to install android a few times recently on different machines and this is the approach Ive taken. You can download eclipse from the eclipse website at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/. (I have the first option Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers).

After that is installed you can install the android sdk using this guide http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-installation/

Also make sure if you want to test on a phone that you go into the android sdk manager (should appear somewhere in eclipse when SDK installed) and download the updates there.

Comment: Your suggestion was a good one and it worked!  Glad to have easy access to Android code once again.